# tr and xargs do not remove space characters

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tr

I am trying to use this command to remove all `<` and `>` and `+` characters from a string. But the command `tr` is inserting a space  character in its place. I want to also remove all spaces.

In

```
<ModelName>.<123456798123465>.
```

Out

```
ModelName . 123456798123465 .
```

Expected Output

```
ModelName.123456798123465.
```

Command used

```
String | tr '<>+,' ' '
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sed  instead of `tr` like below.

```
$ echo '<ModelName>.<123456798123465>.' | sed 's/[+<>]//g'
ModelName.123456798123465.
```

Character class `[+<>]` matches all the `+` or `<` or `>` symbols. By replacing the matched characters with an empty string will give the desired output.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete specific characters, use `tr -d SET`. `tr SET ' '` means to translate all characters in `SET` to space characters.

```
$ echo '<ModelName>.<123456798123465>.' | tr '<>+' ' '
 ModelName . 123456798123465 .
$ echo '<ModelName>.<123456798123465>.' | tr -d '<>+'
ModelName.123456798123465.
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the `-d` option of `tr` command

```
$ echo "<ModelName>.<123456798123465>." | tr -d '<>+,'
ModelName.123456798123465.
```

From the man pages

```
 -d, --delete
              delete characters in SET1, do not translate
```